# Issues with making lstnumber two-digit with hyperref and tcolorbox

Tags: hyperref, listings, tcblisting

I'm trying to use `tcolorbox` and make all lstnumbers two digit. It seems like there is an error with hyperref. I've attached a working example below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}

% define colors for code blocks
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codebackcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={},
  pdftitle={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={},
  pdflang={English},
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=link,
  urlcolor=url,
  citecolor=cite
}
\urlstyle{same}






\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}


% define the code snippet style
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, 
    captionpos=t,
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,
    belowcaptionskip=\medskipamount,
    xleftmargin=0.5em,
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
    stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!60},
    showspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if more keywords should be added to the set
    alsoletter={()[].=},
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={!>}{<!},
    tabsize=1,
    emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},
    columns=fullflexible,
    literate={0}{0}{1}%
             {1}{1}{1}%
             {2}{2}{1}%
             {3}{3}{1}%
             {4}{4}{1}%
             {5}{5}{1}%
             {6}{6}{1}%
             {7}{7}{1}%
             {8}{8}{1}%
             {9}{9}{1}%
             {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
             {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
             {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
             {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
             {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
             {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
             {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
             {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
             {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
             {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
             {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    top=\smallskipamount,
    bottom=2.5\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=0.5cm,
    colframe=gray!20,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=-2mm
    },
    boxed title style={
        size=small,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        boxrule=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        left=0pt
    },
    fonttitle=\color{black},
    listing only,
    listing options={
        style=code
    },
    /codeFormattingKeys/.cd,#1,/tcb/.cd
}

\pgfkeys{
  /codeFormattingKeys/title/.style    = {/tcb/title={\ifx #1\empty\empty\else\ \textbf{Code Snippet~\thetcbcounter.} #1\fi}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/language/.style = {/tcb/listing options app={language=#1}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/file/.style  = {
    /tcb/overlay={
      \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.0mm]frame.north west);
      \end{tcbclipinterior}
      \node[inner sep=0.75mm,rounded corners=0.5mm,anchor=north east,fill=gray!50] at ([xshift=-2.5mm, yshift=\baselineskip + 1mm]frame.south east){\scriptsize\color{violet}\itshape\ttfamily#1};
    },
  }
}

% \renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}} % <--- problem

\definecolor{url}{HTML}{0077bb}
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{882255}
\definecolor{cite}{HTML}{999933}


\begin{document}

{
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents
}


\begin{code}[language=Python, file={\faPython}]
print{"Hello World"}
\end{code}


\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the representation of the `lstnumber` counter:

```
\renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\arabic{lstnumber}%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% <--- no longer necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}

% define colors for code blocks
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{codebackcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}

\usepackage[ttdefault=true]{AnonymousPro}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={},
  pdftitle={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={},
  pdflang={English},
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=link,
  urlcolor=url,
  citecolor=cite
}

\urlstyle{same}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}


% define the code snippet style
\lstdefinestyle{code}{
    numbers=left, 
    numberstyle=\ttfamily\tiny, 
    captionpos=t,
    abovecaptionskip=0pt,
    belowcaptionskip=\medskipamount,
    xleftmargin=0.5em,
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{AnonymousPro}\selectfont,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{pblue},
    stringstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{green!40!black},
    commentstyle=\bfseries\itshape\color{black!60},
    showspaces=false,
    tabsize=2,
    extendedchars=true,
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if more keywords should be added to the set
    alsoletter={()[].=},
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keepspaces=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    escapeinside={!>}{<!},
    tabsize=1,
    emphstyle={\bfseries\color{pblue}},
    columns=fullflexible,
    literate={0}{0}{1}%
             {1}{1}{1}%
             {2}{2}{1}%
             {3}{3}{1}%
             {4}{4}{1}%
             {5}{5}{1}%
             {6}{6}{1}%
             {7}{7}{1}%
             {8}{8}{1}%
             {9}{9}{1}%
             {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
             {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
             {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
             {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
             {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
             {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
             {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
             {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
             {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
             {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
             {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
}

\newtcblisting[auto counter]{code}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    top=\smallskipamount,
    bottom=2.5\smallskipamount,
    sharp corners=downhill,
    arc=0.5cm,
    colframe=gray!20,
    attach boxed title to top left={
        xshift=-2mm
    },
    boxed title style={
        size=small,
        colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        boxrule=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        left=0pt
    },
    fonttitle=\color{black},
    listing only,
    listing options={
        style=code
    },
    /codeFormattingKeys/.cd,#1,/tcb/.cd
}

\pgfkeys{
  /codeFormattingKeys/title/.style    = {/tcb/title={\ifx #1\empty\empty\else\ \textbf{Code Snippet~\thetcbcounter.} #1\fi}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/language/.style = {/tcb/listing options app={language=#1}},
  /codeFormattingKeys/file/.style  = {
    /tcb/overlay={
      \begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \fill[gray!25](frame.south west)
        rectangle ([xshift=5.0mm]frame.north west);
      \end{tcbclipinterior}
      \node[inner sep=0.75mm,rounded corners=0.5mm,anchor=north east,fill=gray!50] at ([xshift=-2.5mm, yshift=\baselineskip + 1mm]frame.south east){\scriptsize\color{violet}\itshape\ttfamily#1};
    },
  }
}

% \renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\makebox[3em][r]{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\the\value{lstnumber}}} % <--- problem

\definecolor{url}{HTML}{0077bb}
\definecolor{link}{HTML}{882255}
\definecolor{cite}{HTML}{999933}

\renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{%
  \ifnum\value{lstnumber}<10 0\fi\arabic{lstnumber}%
}

\begin{document}

{
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
\tableofcontents
}

\section{Code}

\begin{code}[language=Python, file={\faPython}]
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
print{"Hello World"}
\end{code}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. Why did my original attempt not work for this case though?

Comment: @user41177 It was wrong to begin with, I'm afraid: `\thelstnumber` has to be fully expandable and it isn't with `\makebox`.

Comment: Interesting. It's weird that it ran with no errors without hyperref. I took that snippet from the answer to another question.